# R code generated from table in SQL Server won't be executed

Tags: sql-server, r

I tried to run R code created from database given in [How to make R-code from SQL Server database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45435205/how-to-make-r-code-from-sql-server-database) but I was unable to execute it.

Here is what I tried.

```
declare @t table(f1 int, f2 int)
insert into @t values (1,2),(3,4),(5,6)

declare @rcode nvarchar(max) = 
concat(
'f1=c(', STUFF( (SELECT concat(',', f1)
            FROM @t
            ORDER BY f1
            FOR XML PATH('')),1, 1, ''),')
f2=c(',  STUFF( (SELECT concat(',', f2)
            FROM @t
            ORDER BY f1
            FOR XML PATH('')),1, 1, ''),')'
        )

select @rcode
EXECUTE sp_execute_external_script
    @language = N'R'
   , @script = N'@rcode'
```

The code outputs

> Msg 39004, Level 16, State 20, Line 0
>   A 'R' script error occurred during execution of 'sp_execute_external_script' with HRESULT 0x80004004.
>
> Msg 39019, Level 16, State 1, Line 0
>   An external script error occurred:
>   Error in source(revoScriptConnection) :
>   revoScriptConnection:1:1: unexpected '@'
>   1: @
>      ^
>
> Error in ScaleR. Check the output for more information.
>   Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) :
>   Error in ScaleR.  Check the output for more information.
>   Calls: source -> withVisible -> eval -> eval -> .Call
>   Execution halted

I also tried to add input and output data to the query but as in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/advanced-analytics/tutorials/rtsql-create-a-predictive-model-r but it still won't run.

How can I see the result of R code that is generated from the data in table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that it is easier to pass variables via SQL-statements like this

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS alpha;
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE alpha
AS
BEGIN
    EXEC sp_execute_external_script
    @language = N'R'
    , @script = N'R-code'
    , @input_data_1 = N'SQL SELECT statement'
    , @input_data_1_name = N'Test'
END;
GO
EXEC alpha;
```

Answer (score 0):

@script parameter expects a string value to be used as an R script. In this case, the string passed is '@rcode'. To assign the value of the variable @rcode use without the quote.

```
declare @t table(f1 int, f2 int)
insert into @t values (1,2),(3,4),(5,6)

declare @rcode nvarchar(max) = 
concat(
'f1=c(', STUFF( (SELECT concat(',', f1)
            FROM @t
            ORDER BY f1
            FOR XML PATH('')),1, 1, ''),')
f2=c(',  STUFF( (SELECT concat(',', f2)
            FROM @t
            ORDER BY f1
            FOR XML PATH('')),1, 1, ''),')'
        )

select @rcode
EXECUTE sp_execute_external_script
    @language = N'R'
   , @script = @rcode
```

Comment: It looks like this does not work. I got f1=c(1,3,5) f2=c(2,4,6) but in R, the code outputs two vectors.